# How to install paytm payment in odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, paytm

How can I include/install  [Paytm](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/paytm_payment_gateway/)  in my ecommerce Odoo website v13 and I can not find in apps.

Answer (score 0):

This module uses the Crypto python library so you need first to install python library as below:

pip3 install pycryptodome

Then you will add the module folder to your addons/custom addons folder and restarted the Odoo service. you have to go to Apps -> click update app lists. then search for paytm_payment_gateway and install it.

Once the apps installed go to Accounting app -> Configurations -> Payment Acquirers and you will find it there so you can enable it and add your configuration.